# Prove that $\langle x,y \rangle = 0$ iff $\|x+cy\| \geq \|x\|$ for all real $c$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have tried expanding the inequality with $\|x+cy\| = \langle x+cy,x+cy\rangle^{1/2} $ and using the properties of the inner product but to no avail.

Comment: Is the space real or complex?

Comment: The space is real.

Comment: See Question 6 here: http://linearalgebras.com/6a.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider
$$\|x+cy\|^2=\|x\|^2+2c\left<x,y\right>+c^2\|y\|^2=f(c)$$
say. Then $f'(0)$ must equal zero, for $f$ to have a minimum at $0$.
But $f'(0)=2\left<x,y\right>$.

Comment: Why must this quadratic in $c$ have a minimum at $0$? Wouldn't the point at which it has a minimum depend on the coefficients $\|x\|^2$, $\|y\|^2$ and $\langle x,y\rangle$?

Comment: @tmaj The point is that $f$ has a minimum at $0$ iff $f'(0)=0$.